Data is not being inserted in Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA.and getting batabase value is null {}
I have created a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA.
The problem is that while inserting data into the database, it shows that the data has been inserted, but there is actually no data in the database.
When trying to postman I'm getting below ouput :

Following is my code.
pojo class :
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Quiz {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   private String title;
}

QuizRepo.java :
public interface QuizRepository  extends JpaRepository<Quiz, Long>{
    
}

In the above entity class, we are using Lombok annotations to create the setters, getters, and constructors, but the data is not being inserted. When we create the setters, getters, and constructors manually, it works. Below is the updated code :
@Entity
public class Quiz {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   private String title;
        
   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }
    
   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
    
   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }
    
   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }
    
   public Quiz() {
      super();
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
    
   public Quiz(Long id, String title) {
      super();
      this.id = id;
      this.title = title;
   }
    
   @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Quiz [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + "]";
      }
   }

After updating the code, I am able to retrieve data from the database and insert data into the database without any null values.


Enable Annotation Processing: If you're using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, ensure annotation processing is enabled:
IntelliJ: Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors and check 'Enable annotation processing.'
Eclipse: Right-click on your project > Properties > Java Compiler > Annotation Processing and ensure it's enabled.

You need to enable annotation processing in the IntelliJ.
Go to settings and search for Annotation Processing & just enable, then click Apply and then run. It should work fine.
